# Check Unit testing in C: Best way to test static methods

Tags: c, unit-testing, static-methods

I am using Check framework do to unit testing of my C code, and I couldn't find a proper way to test the static methods.

My work around, is not ideal at all and would like if someone can point me in the right direction on how to do it properly. My work around is simply by add #ifdef macro that changes the static methods to extern in case I pass -D DEBUG at compile time.

In the source file

```
#ifdef DEBUG
unsigned ds_roundup_to_prime (const unsigned bsize) {
#else
static inline unsigned ds_roundup_to_prime (const unsigned bsize) {
#endif
```

And in the header file I do

```
#ifdef DEBUG
unsigned ds_roundup_to_prime (const unsigned bsize);
#endif
```

Ideally source code shouldn't change to cater for unit tests. Unit-test framework, should must be capable of testing the source code as it will look in production.

Thanks

Comment: You can dress it up prettier, such as your first answer describes, but if you want to call a function from a different source file then there's no getting around the requirement that the function to be called have external linkage.  That's pretty much what external linkage *means*.

Comment: @John I'd say my solution does indeed get around it.

Comment: Technically, perhaps, @JonathonReinhart. It would have been more precise for me to say "from a different translation unit".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's debatable whether or not `static` functions should be tested, as they aren't part of the public API.

I test `static` functions by including the unit-under-test, rather than linking against it:

**foo.c** (Unit under test)

```
static int foo(int x)
{
    return x;
}

/* ... */
```

**test_foo.c**

```
#include "foo.c"

void test_foo(void)
{
    assert( foo(42) == 42 );
}

int main(void)
{
    test_foo();
}
```

Compile just that test:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -o test_foo test_foo.c
$ ./test_foo
```

Comment: That's interesting, though I remember being taught in school, you should never `include` a source file.  Maybe you have problems with function be redefined?

Comment: In general you shouldn't. But this is for unit-testing, not building normal software. You only build the test source file, and not the unit under test.

Comment: I tried this but I have my structs and some macros defined in the header and I need them in the static methods...

Comment: @Fiddling Bits - My first thought was "That's *horrible*!"  Then I thought "Unit test?  For a static function in C?"  It's actually pretty ingenious - I like it :)

Comment: Each `test` has to be independent (i.e. have it's own `main`) but it does make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Rami So? Why can't that header file be included as it. Normally would? This is just an exercise in setting up the include paths correctly in your build system.

Comment: The source file containing the static functions in question must already include any headers providing declarations of types and functions it uses, so that oughtn't to be an issue.  I am nevertheless of two minds about this.  When doing it this way, there is a risk of perturbing the function under test that is not present when all you do is change its linkage.

Comment: Worked perfectly... the issue I had initially with including the .c file was I forgot to change the Makefile to exclude the imported .c file from compilation as it is included in the test .c file anyway. Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 3):

I test `static` functions in the following manner.

I have a header file called `utility.h`.  It has the following definition:

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
  #define UTILITY_STATIC(DECLARATION) extern DECLARATION; DECLARATION
#else
  #define UTILITY_STATIC(DECLARATION) static DECLARATION
#endif
```

Every source file that has functions that are to be tested are declared as such:

```
#include "utility.h"
UTILITY_STATIC(void function(void));
UTILITY_STATIC(void function(void))
{
}
```

I have an additional header file (e.g. `test_helper.h`), used in the unit test executable, that has the line:

```
extern void function(void);
```

In this way, tests have access to `function` whereas source files that don't `define` `UNIT_TEST` do not.

**Note**

This can be used for `static` variables as well.

Comment: That looks interesting, can you please show me a sample method.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Check. I've been using [Unity](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity/).